# Django admin documentation generator not formatting Docstrings for Models

Tags: python, django, django-admin, documentation-generation

I'm currently in the process of documenting all of my django views and models using the Django admin documentation generator. While I haven't had any problems at all documenting views, however anything written in the docstrings of my Models are rendered just as plaintext in the documentation.

In other words, if I want to reference a view:

```
:view:`appname.view_name`
```

will be rendered as a link (what I want) if inserted into the docstring of a view, but will show up as ":view:`appname.view_name`" in plaintext when inserted into the docstring of any model. However, when inserted in model's method, formatting works as expected again.

At first I thought this was a quirk of the documentation generator, that maybe it doesn't read the markup for model docstrings, but after reading the documentation (found here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/admin/admindocs/#model-reference ) it seems that you I should be able to link to other parts of the documentation.

I haven't seen anyone else having this problem, and I'm not sure where to start looking for a solution. Thanks in advance for any expertise and explanations.

EDIT:

It seems like formatting is skipped entirely in Model's docstring - ie it will ignore reStructured text.

For example

class MyModel(models.Model):

"""

**Title**

"""

will show up simply as **Title** in plaintext in django admin docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django admin document generator currently (1.7 at time of writing) does not support reStructure text in model docstrings.

This was addressed in card [#5405](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/5405) but still hasn't been merged in master as it created some merge conflicts. Last change:

> I left comments on the ​pull request but it still needs some improvement including a rebase to merge cleanly. It would also be good to mention the change in the release notes.

Comment: The question is updated with that additional information. It would be nice if this made it in the next patch.

Comment: @starr749 it would, although it's not looking too optimistic, based on the dates on the ticket. I've also been disappointed that model methods with arguments don't get documented

Comment: Update: this will get patched in 1.8