# reStructuredText in docstring is rendered as plain text in admindocs in Python, Django

Tags: python, django, docstring

Admin documentation generator (`admindocs`) works strangely in Django. I supposed that this docstring must be rendered as hyperlink to documentation page on `User` model.

```
"""
:model:`auth.User`
"""
```

But:

- in view this docstring is rendered as text "auth.User" but with no hyperlink
- in model this docstring is rendered merely as plain text

I followed [these](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/admindocs/) instructions to activate `admindocs`

I am using Django 1.6.7. and docutils 0.12

**upd**

as for model [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22230904/django-admin-documentation-generator-not-formatting-docstrings-for-models) looks like to be the answer